# Book for Django + Celery + RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

OK, I have been reading about the `celery` and `rabbitmq`, while I appreciate the effort of the project and the documentation, I am still confused about a lot of things.

http://www.celeryproject.org/

http://ask.github.com/django-celery/

I am super confused about if celery is only for Django or a standalone server, as the second link claims `celery` is tightly used with Django. Both sites show different ways of setting up and using `celery`, which to me is chaotic.

Enough rant, is there a proper book available that I can buy?

Comment: also, I am not able to find much info about what celeryd_multi really is, when I run the first time, it looks like a command line server, but running celeryd_multi it puts the server in background as daemon. Any ideas?
1) CELERYD="/var/www/queuemanager/manage.py celeryd"                
2) CELERYD_MULTI="/var/www/queuemanager/manage.py celeryd_multi"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well not a book but I recently did setup in Dotcloud for Django+Celery, and here's the short doc:
http://web.archive.org/web/20150329132442/http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django-celery/

It's intended for simple tasks to be run asynchronously. There is a dotcloud-specific setup, but the rest might clear things up a bit. AFAIK, Celery started tightly coupled with Django but later became an entirely different animal, although it still retains superb compatibility with Django.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a book, I guess a quick Amazon search would dig that up.

The bottom line is, celery is run as a separate server and works just as well for a standalone python program as Django, so it is not tied directly to Django. You can also run the `celeryd` worker software on multiple computers so they can all process the same queue concurrently. Often a separate queueing server, such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is run to store the queue message.

Keep in mind, `django-celery` is just an integration app that acts as glue between Django and Celery.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a long time back and the celery docs have been significantly spruced up since, it'd be good to start with the FAQ's to allay queries of this nature.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-celery-for-django-only